# Scrolling - jQuery shows hidden content when it is reached

Tags: jquery, scroll, single-page-application, infinite

I've been following this example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/gRzPF/12/

...to automatically load more content when the user reaches the end of the currently displayed content. **Unfortunately the example only seems to work when the .content div has a set height in pixels in the CSS.**

How can I achieve the desired result **without setting a height**? I've got a tonne of information on a single page, broken up into several sections, that I want hidden before the users scrolls to it, at which point it appears.

Been looking at infinite scrolling plugins, but all the examples seem to only be for remote content. I basically need the same thing but for content on the one page. I'm only competent with HTML/CSS, I can insert jQuery and play around with values a little, but am otherwise terrible with it...

---

**jQuery**

```
//Set intital divs to be hidden
$(".content").addClass("noshow");
    var contentNumber = 0;

    function reveal() {
        var constraintNumber = contentNumber + 6;
        //IMPORTANT - DO NOT DELETE
        $(window).trigger('resize');
        //IMPORTANT - DO NOT DELETE
        for (i = contentNumber; i < constraintNumber; i++) {
            //Get the nth div of class content, where n is the contentNumber, and make it shown
            $('.content').eq(contentNumber).removeClass("noshow");
            contentNumber ++;
        }
    }

//Window scroll function
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() )
        {
        reveal();
        }
});
reveal();
```

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">I have some content</div>
<div class="content">I have some content</div>
<div class="content">I have some content</div>
<div class="content">I have some content</div>
<div class="content">I have some content</div>
<div class="content">I have some content</div>
<div class="content">I have some content</div>
<div class="content">I have some content</div>
<div class="content">I have some content</div>
<div class="content">I have some content</div>
<div class="content">I have some content</div>
<div class="content">I have some content</div>
<div class="content">I have some content</div>
<div class="content">I have some content</div>
<div class="content">I have some content</div>
<div class="content">I have some content</div>
<div class="content">I have some content</div>
<div class="content">I have some content</div>
<div class="content">I have some content</div>
<div class="content">I have some content</div>
<div class="content">I have some content</div>
<div class="content">I have some content</div>
```

---

**CSS**

```
.content {
    margin: 1px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    background-color: gray;
}

.noshow{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the height to "auto". I tried succesfully in your fiddle after putting some more content into the DIVs.

Answer (score 0):

Even without setting height it will scroll. Make sure that there are enough number of div having class 'content' and content inside the div that will create scroll bar at first page load.

You can try removing float:left from the css